# Getting SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE and HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO with ngrok and dotnet

Tags: asp.net, .net, ngrok

I am trying to run a dotnet api from my local machine and test an IOT device that has wireless capability, so I need to create a tunnel for my local machine api to be accessible from the outside world for the device.

I have previously used ngrok for this sort of thing but seem to be running into SSL issues.

I have tried a number of different ngrok commands

```bash
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite --scheme=https https://localhost:7063
ngrok http https://localhost:7063
ngrok http --host-header=localhost:7063 https://localhost:7063
ngrok http 7063
```

All get the a similar error, from the IOT device, Postman, and curl.

Postman gives this:

```
Error: write EPROTO 5026831912:error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:594:SSL alert number 40
5026831912:error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake.cc:644:
```

Curl gives this:

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:1404B410:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have run `brew update` `brew upgrade` and got the latest version of ngrok, I have the latest version of openssl. I have cleaned and redone my dotnet https certs with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` ... the calls work via postman locally if I just use the `https://localhost:7063` address. But when I use the address given by ngrok I just get the SSL errors.

System info as follows:

```
MacBook Pro M1 Pro
32GB RAM
Ventura 13.3.1
API - dotnet6
ngrok - 3.2.2
```